# gensim - Word2vec continue training on existing model - AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'compute_loss'

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I am trying to continue training on an existing model,

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('model/corpus.zhwiki.word.model')
more_sentences = [['Advanced', 'users', 'can', 'load', 'a', 'model', 'and', 'continue', 'training', 'it', 'with', 'more', 'sentences']]    
model.build_vocab(more_sentences, update=True)
model.train(more_sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
```

but I got an error with the last line:

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'compute_loss'

Some posts said it's caused by using a earlier version of gensim, and I have tried to add this after loading the existing model and before train().

```
model.compute_loss = False
```

After that, it didn't give me the AttributeError, but the output of model.train() is 0, and model didn't trained with new sentences.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I continues training my model

```
# training_data: initial training data. contain list of tokenized sentences
model = Word2Vec(training_data, size=50, window=5, min_count=10, workers=4)

# datasmall: more sentences
# total_examples: number of additional sentence
# epochs: provide your current epochs. model.epochs is ok 
model.train(datasmall, total_examples=len(datasmall), epochs=model.epochs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `total_examples` (and `epochs`) arguments to `train()` should match what you're currently providing, in your `more_sentences` – not leftover values from prior training.

So for example, given your code showing just a single additional sentence, you'd specify `total_examples=1`.

If this isn't the source of the problem, double check that `more_sentences` is what you expect it to be at the time of the `train()` call.

Comment: I have changed total_examples=1, and epochs=1, but it also gave me the same results. And the `more_sentences` also has the value that that I expect to put in the train() method

Comment: Are you sure all the words in the new text appear more often than `min_count`? (All words being skipped for being low-frequency would be a possible explanation for a `0` trained-word count.)

Comment: Ya, that is possible, but in 'train()' method I can't give the 'min_count' parameter. Maybe the 'min_count' is too low in the original model? is there any way to set/change 'min_count'?

Comment: If infrequent words you'd like retained are being lost, the original `min_count` is too high You might be able to direct-reassign `model.min_count` before doing your `build_vocab(..., update=True)`. However, note that eliminating low-frequency words is usually good for vector-quality & training-time – and a process of adding individual new sentences is unlikely to work well. (A model become self-consistently good via the interleaved training of many varied examples; toy-sized corpuses or toy-sized updates are unlikely to work well.)